# Having problem with product images, Magento is adding a faint pattern over images

Tags: product-images, image-upload

I'm fairly new to Magento. My problem is that when uploading images to Magento, it's adding a very light square pattern over the images. It's as if it's trying to apply a watermark that doesn't exist over them. I've checked the originals, and they are fine, no odd pattern is present, but the large image on the product page has this very very faint texture on it.

I had previously added a watermark, but when I discovered how terrible the watermarking quality is on Magento removed it. This pattern appears to be applied to all my images, including new ones added since removing the watermark. (Also, this pattern has nothing in common with the watermark I had previously used, so maybe the whole watermark thing has nothing to do with it…?)

I've cleared the image cache and that hasn't changed anything.

Any ideas why, and what I can do to resolve this, thank you.

Comment: Is watermark enabled? see http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/using-product-image-watermarks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Enabled", all of the fields in the watermark section of my site are clear, I can't see an option for "Disabling" watermarks…

Comment: @SteveMcC were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?